# How to edit plotly gauge plot ticks in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'm having trouble removing the ticks on my plotly gauge chart and having the start (min) and end (max) ticks to be underneath the graph.

this is the code I'm using to create my gauge.

```
plot1 <- plotly::plot_ly(
  type = "indicator",
  mode = "gauge+number",
  value = 42.2,
  title = list(text = "Jump Height", font = list(size = 30, color = "white")),
  gauge = list(
    axis = list(range = list(NULL, 50), tickfont = list(color = "black"), tickcolor = "black", ticks = ""),
    bar = list(color = "royalblue", thickness = 1),
    bgcolor = "white",
    borderwidth = 0))
plot1 <- plot1 %>% plotly::layout(
  margin = list(t=20,r=20,b=20,l=20),
  paper_bgcolor = "black",
  font = list(color = "white", family = "Arial"))

plot1
```

as you can see the ticks are there in the graph but i've just adjusted the colors so they blend into the background and dont show. I've even tried using tickvals, ticktext, tickmode, and tickangle to get the labels where i want them but then my title gets all messed up.

I'd like my gauge to resemble something like this.

[image]

if anyone knows an alternate in ggplot2 that would be great too!

Answer (score 1):

This function will produce a ggplot that does the trick. Just give it the number you want to represent and the gauge upper limit. You can specify the color of the gauge and the title too:

```r
make_gauge <- function(x, n, color =  "#ef8d49", title = NULL) {
  data.frame(x = c(5 * cos(seq(-pi, 0, len = 100)), 
                   3 * cos(seq(0, -pi, len = 100)),
                   5 * cos(seq(-pi, -pi + pi * x/n, len = 100)),
                   3 * cos(seq( -pi + pi * x/n, -pi, len = 100))),
             y = c(5 * -sin(seq(-pi, 0, len = 100)), 
                   3 * -sin(seq(0, -pi, len = 100)),
                   5 * -sin(seq(-pi, -pi + pi * x/n, len = 100)),
                   3 * -sin(seq( -pi + pi * x/n, -pi, len = 100))),
             group = rep(c("off", "on"), each = 200)) |>
    ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = group)) +
    geom_polygon() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#eceaea", color), guide = "none") +
    annotate("text", x = c(-4, 0, 4), y = c(-0.5, 0.6, -0.5),
             label = c(0, round(42.2, 1), 50), size = c(12, 30, 12),
             colour = c("#c8c8c8", "#808080", "#c8c8c8"), 
             fontface = 2) +
    ggtitle(title) +
    coord_equal() +
    theme_void() +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 40, color = "#808080",
                                    vjust = 2, face = 2))
}
```

Testing, we have:

```
make_gauge(42.2, 50, title = "Jump Height")
```

[image]